# Какое значение и происхождение у словосочетания «э волату»?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, литература

> Ты славный малый; но ты все-таки мякенький, либеральный барич — ***э волату***, как выражается мой родитель.
>
> *И. С. Тургенев «Отцы и дети»*

В *[Словаре забытых и трудных слов из произведений русской литературы ХVIII-ХIХ веков. сост. Л. А. Глинкина](https://difficult_words_ru.academic.ru/425/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83)* приводится такое толкование слова «волату»:

> **Волату́**, *неизм.*
>
> Вот и все.
>
> *Ну, может быть, может быть, — спорить не стану. Ведь я что? Отставной штаб-лекарь, волату.*
> Тургенев. Отцы и дети.

Получается, что значение может быть такое:
*Ты славный малый; но ты все-таки мякенький, либеральный барич — ***вот и все***...*

Однако, перед «волату» есть «э», которого нет в словаре, и оно в [тексте](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_(%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2)/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_26) выделено курсивом вместе с «волату», а значит это какое-то словосочетание.

В этимологических словарях не удаётся найти происхождение. Возможно, это некое изречение из другого языка.

---

- Какое значение у «э волату» в приведенной цитате?
- Что означает «э», которого нет в словаре?
- Какая этимология у «э волату»?

Comment: "Et voila tout" — это французский. Прононс оставляем на совести "родителя" (впрочем, звучит похоже). Вообще, если встречаете что-то подобное незнакомое в книгах классиков XIX в., в первую очередь следует свериться с французским (по очевидным причинам).

Comment: @grizzly Я тоже так думаю и искал во французском, однако я искал «волату», как одно слово. Напишите, пожалуйста, как ответ, если хотите. Потому что я не могу принять комментарий, как правильный ответ.

Comment: Лень расписывать подробнее. Но если Вас настолько краткий ответ устроит, тогда ладно :) Вопрос мне понравился — сам с удовольствием решил эту головоломку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Et voila tout" — это французский. Прононс оставляем на совести "родителя" (впрочем, звучит похоже).